# How do you install a plugin through the command line?

Tags: plugins, install, cli

I would like to install and enable plugins through the command line in a way that can be scripted, and which replicates the same steps as are taken when you install a plugin through the Craft control panel.

What commands are necessary to accomplish this?

Would this be enough?

```
composer require repo/plugin-name
./craft install/plugin plugin-slug
```

Will these two commands also install the plugin migrations, enable the plugin, and update the `project.yaml` file, just as if I had installed the plugin through the control panel?

Is it also necessary to run `./craft migrate/all`? Or `./craft clear-caches/all`?

Also, is it possible to install a specific plugin edition (e.g. Lite or Pro) through the command line?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to now be reversed: `plugin/install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will these two commands also install the plugin migrations

There will be no migrations to run since it is a brand new installation.

> enable the plugin, and update the project.yaml file, just as if I had installed the plugin through the control panel?

Yes to both.

> Is it also necessary to run ./craft migrate/all? Or ./craft clear-caches/all?

Nope.

> Also, is it possible to install a specific plugin edition (e.g. Lite or Pro) through the command line?

Not natively. If a plugin has multiple editions, it will default to whatever is listed in their `getEditions()` method, which is typically going to be "Lite" first.

Comment: You can potentially use `Craft:$app->plugins->setEdition('plugin-handle', 'edition');` in a content migration or modify the edition key in projectConfig to "force" the edition of a plugin, but I don't think it's an official way. Going through the Craft ID/store would be.